# How to combine consecutive strings based on values in another list and conditions?

Tags: python, string, list, conditional-statements

I have 2 lists:

```
tokens = ['[CLS]', 'Thinking', 'historically', 'is', ',', 'first', ',', 'an', 'attitude', 'acknowledging', 'that', 'every', 'event', 'can', 'be', 'meaningful', '##ly', 'understood', 'only', 'in', 'relation', 'to', 'previous', 'events', ',', 'and', ',', 'second', ',', 'the', 'method', '##ical', 'application', 'of', 'this', 'attitude', ',', 'which', 'en', '##tails', 'both', 'analyzing', 'events', 'context', '##ually', '-', '-', 'as', 'having', 'occurred', 'in', 'the', 'midst', 'of', 'pre', '-', 'existing', 'circumstances', '-', '-', 'and', 'comprehend', '##ing', 'them', 'from', 'historical', 'actors', '[SEP]', '[PAD]', '[PAD]', '[PAD]']
labels = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
```

I also have a dictionary that maps the labels to their meaning:

```
labels_meaning = {}
labels_meaning[0] = 'subject'
labels_meaning[1] = 'relation'
labels_meaning[2] = 'object'
labels_meaning[3] = 'na'
```

The goal is to place each string in their corresponding `labels_list` (ignoring `na`):

```
subjects = []
relations = []
objects = []
```

There are 3 conditions:

1. Combining tokens that have consecutive label (e.g., 0, 0, 0) into one string. e.g., the first 5 labels are 0s, hence the first string should be `"[CLS] Thinking historically is ,"`, which should be appended to the corresponding `labels_list`: `subjects.append(string)`
2. If a token has the string `"##"` in it, it should be concatenated with the previous string without spaces. e.g., `"meaningful", "##ly" --> "meaningfully"`. Assuming they have the same label. Otherwise the `"##"` should be removed and the string should be appended to the corresponding `labels_list`: `subjects.append("ly")`
3. A few tokens should be ignored: `[CLS], [SEP], [PAD]`

Update:

Adding my attempt, but I'm stuck on combining the consecutive tokens

```
labels_meaning = {}
labels_meaning[0] = 'subject'
labels_meaning[1] = 'relation'
labels_meaning[2] = 'object'
labels_meaning[3] = 'na'
ignore = ['[CLS]', '[SEP]', '[PAD]']

def get_sentence_triples_from_token_labels(tokens, token_labels):
    for tok, label in zip(tokens, token_labels):
        current_label = label
        if tok == '[CLS]': # initialize
            previous_label = current_label
            prev = False
            current_string = ''
        if tok not in ignore:
            if previous_label != current_label and prev==True:
                current_string = f'{tok} ' 
                pass
                
            else:
                pass
            
            prev = True


        break


get_sentence_triples_from_token_labels(tokens, labels)
```

Comment: It would be better if you can show your try or effort. Or at least show the error you get. Rather than just ask "hey, do this for me."  check [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is recommend.

Comment: @XinCheng added my attempt but I'm not sure how to do this. Hence the SO question.

Comment: Good, let me check that.

Comment: @XinCheng Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### solution

Not sure if this is what you wan.

```py
labels_meaning = { 0:'subject', 1:'relation', 2:'object', 3:'na' }
ignore = ['[CLS]', '[SEP]', '[PAD]']


tokens = ['[CLS]', 'Thinking', 'historically', 'is', ',', 'first', ',', 'an', 'attitude', 'acknowledging', 'that', 'every', 'event', 'can', 'be', 'meaningful', '##ly', 'understood', 'only', 'in', 'relation', 'to', 'previous', 'events', ',', 'and', ',', 'second', ',', 'the', 'method', '##ical', 'application', 'of', 'this', 'attitude', ',', 'which', 'en', '##tails', 'both', 'analyzing', 'events', 'context', '##ually', '-', '-', 'as', 'having', 'occurred', 'in', 'the', 'midst', 'of', 'pre', '-', 'existing', 'circumstances', '-', '-', 'and', 'comprehend', '##ing', 'them', 'from', 'historical', 'actors', '[SEP]', '[PAD]', '[PAD]', '[PAD]']
labels = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]

subjects = []
relations = []
objects = []

def get_sentence_triples_from_token_labels(tokens, token_labels):
    dicRlt = {lab:[] for lab in [0,1,2,3]}
    last_label = token_labels[0]
    for tok, label in zip(tokens, token_labels):
        if tok not in ignore:
            if last_label != label:
                if label == 0: 
                    subjects.append(" ".join(dicRlt[0]).replace(" ##",""))
                elif label == 1:
                    relations.append(" ".join(dicRlt[1]).replace(" ##",""))
                elif label == 2: 
                    objects.append(" ".join(dicRlt[2]).replace(" ##",""))
                dicRlt[label]=[]
            dicRlt[label].append(tok)                
            last_label = label
    subjects.append(" ".join(dicRlt[0]).replace(" ##",""))
    relations.append(" ".join(dicRlt[1]).replace(" ##",""))
    objects.append(" ".join(dicRlt[2]).replace(" ##",""))
    return
```

- Test

  ```
  print(subjects)
  print(relations)
  print(objects)
  ```
- Outpu:

  ```
  ['Thinking historically is ,', 'attitude', 'that every event can be meaningfully understood only', 'relation', 'previous events ,', ', second', 'methodical', 'attitude', 'entails', 'events contextually -', 'as having occurred in', 'circumstances -', 'comprehend', 'them from', 'actors']
  ['', ', an', 'acknowledging', 'in', 'to', 'and', ', the', 'application of this', ', which', 'both analyzing', '-', 'the midst of pre - existing', '- and', '##ing', 'historical']
  ['', 'first']
  ```

Comment: Still going over it, but I don't really see the part about appending each string to their corresponding `labels_list`. e.g., `subjects.append("Thinking historically is ,")`. Am I missing it?

Comment: I recommend you need to understand it and then customize it to full fill your requirements.

Comment: I think I do understand. Seems like you are just concatenating each token into one big string (`dicRlt[label].append(tok)`) instead of dealing with the consecutive parts which is the issue. It is apparent when you print `subjects`. It should be multiple strings but instead it is just one

Comment: updated with each string insert once.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot! I just changed the replace in the append statements to  `.replace("##","")` instead. i.e., removing the space before the ##. Otherwise if you change the label of `##ly` from 0 to 2 it adds "##ly" to `objects`